# emacs org-mode: htmlize leaves keywords in exported html

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode, htmlize.el

I didn't manage to keep syntax highlightning of source blocks in org-mode html-export with C-c C-e h h, so I switched to htmlize as suggested in some other posts here. It does fine with manually doing M-x htmlize-buffer, except for the fact it leaves all org-mode keywords beginning with #+ in the exported html. I tried org-mode 7.x as well as 8.2.5 now in emacs 24.3.1. I already thought of writing a short python-script to fix this afterwards, but maybe someone knows a quicker solution?

TNX a lot for any suggestions

barrios

Comment: I get syntax highlighting of source blocks with *no* configuration (i.e. `emacs -Q`)
Emacs 24.3.50.1, `org-mode` from git.

Comment: yes, in emacs it is no problem, but please try to preserve it when _exporting to html_ with C-c C-e h h. Does this also work in your more current version? Then I'd surely upgrade :-)

Comment: Yes, both on export and inside Emacs. All I do is setup load path to git and `(require 'org)`.

Comment: Actually, it also works for 24.3, just checked. So the main component is org from git.

Comment: I only found how to clone & compile org from git or to use org-track for upgrading to the current devel. Could you please show me how you set your load-path to git, this seems more simple und elegant to me, especially in case of downgrading again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up org mode from git.

```bsh
    mkdir ~/git
    cd ~/git
    git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
    cd org-mode
    make up2
```

2. Optionally, edit `~/git/org-mode/local.mk`. I've set

```Makefile
    lispdir= ~/Dropbox/source/site-lisp/org
```

3. Create `~/tinit.el` with contents:

```lisp
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/source/site-lisp/org")
    (require 'org)
```

4. Test it with

```bash
    emacs -Q -l ~/tinit.el ~/foo.org
```

If everything works, merge `~/tinit.el` into your config.